# Arithmetic Coding Compression Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement arithmetic coding which is a compression algorithm. Here is the compression code in which when I compiled it, it shows "Usage: java ArithmeticCompress InputFile OutputFile" every time. I already give file path but don't understand what's the problem?

```
public class ArithmeticCompress {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Show what command line arguments to use
        if (args.length == 0) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java ArithmeticCompress InputFile OutputFile");
            System.exit(1);
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise, compress

        File inputFile = new File("E:\\output\\5.txt", args[0]);
        File outputFile = new File("E:\\output\\new.txt", args[1]);

        // Read input file once to compute symbol frequencies
        FrequencyTable freq = getFrequencies(inputFile);
        freq.increment(256);  // EOF symbol gets a frequency of 1

        // Read input file again, compress with arithmetic coding, and write output file
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFile));
        BitOutputStream out = new BitOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile)));
        try {
            writeFrequencies(out, freq);
            compress(freq, in, out);
        } finally {
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }


    private static FrequencyTable getFrequencies(File file) throws IOException {
        FrequencyTable freq = new SimpleFrequencyTable(new int[257]);
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        try {
            while (true) {
                int b = input.read();
                if (b == -1)
                    break;
                freq.increment(b);
            }
        } finally {
            input.close();
        }
        return freq;
    }


    static void writeFrequencies(BitOutputStream out, FrequencyTable freq) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            writeInt(out, 32, freq.get(i));
    }


    static void compress(FrequencyTable freq, InputStream in, BitOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        ArithmeticEncoder enc = new ArithmeticEncoder(out);
        while (true) {
            int b = in.read();
            if (b == -1)
                break;
            enc.write(freq, b);
        }
        enc.write(freq, 256);  // EOF
        enc.finish();
    }


    private static void writeInt(BitOutputStream out, int numbits, int value) throws IOException {
        if (numbits < 0 || numbits > 32)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        for (int i = 0; i < numbits; i++)
            out.write(value >>> i & 1);  // Little endian
    }

}
```

Comment: how you are passing command line arguments??

Comment: Source: http://www.nayuki.io/page/arithmetic-coding-java

Answer (score 3):

You said you already gave the file path.  However, you tried to put the file path in the program itself, not on the command line:

```
File inputFile = new File("E:\\output\\5.txt", args[0]);
```

That isn't good enough.  If the program expects the file path to be on the command line, you have to put it on the command line when you run it (see the other answers).  Java will not look at your program and figure out that you really had the path name in your program.  Computers simply aren't that smart.

You'll need to decide.  If you want the file path to be in the program, then get rid of the code that checks for `args.length`, and don't use `args` in the `new File` constructors:

```
File inputFile = new File("E:\\output\\5.txt");
File outputFile = new File("E:\\output\\new.txt");
```

If you want the files to be specified on the command line, change the code to this:

```
File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
File outputFile = new File(args[1]);
```

and make sure you specify the path names when you run the program with `java`.

**THIS WILL NOT WORK:**

```
File inputFile = new File("E:\\output\\5.txt", args[0]);
```

because now it will look for a file named something like `E:\output\5.txt\yourInputFile.txt`.  In other words, it will think `5.txt` is a folder.  That's what it thinks you mean when you use `new File` with two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The message says what's wrong. You need to run the jar file as

```
java ArithmeticCompress InputFile OutputFile
```

So if you name your jar file ArithmicCompress with ArithmicCompress as main class, running it with an input file and output file argument should skip that part and try to run it.

Basically, it now says that you're not supplying arguments, so either another class is being run as main class instead or you aren't supplying arguments.

If you're sure you are supplying arguments, verify it using the following snippet in whatever class is running, it should return the arguments you give it;

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

Comment: In addition to providing the correct arguments: You should check if `args.length != 2` instead of `args.length == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

run your java program as below command where input file name will be absolute path of input file and output file name will be absolute path of output file.

```
java <class-name> "<input file name>" "<output file name>"
```

Comment: Important thing is the double quotes. `C:\Program Files\ ` is not the same as `"C:\Program Files\"`.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems you are not having understanding of args and about File Class constructor.

Let me explain the code here to help you understand the problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Show what command line arguments to use
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.err.println("Usage: java ArithmeticCompress InputFile OutputFile");
        System.exit(1);
        return;
    }

   ..some code...

    File inputFile = new File("E:\\output\\5.txt", args[0]);
    File outputFile = new File("E:\\output\\new.txt", args[1]);

   ..some code...
}
```

---

1. Here `main(String[] args)` means while this program is run from command line you can provide multiple String arguments like this: `java ClassName argument1 argument2 ...`

   and these argument can be accessed in your main function as args[0], args[1], args[2] respectively.. 
   because `String[] args` is a array of Strings.

   So if you see the comparison   `if (args.length == 0)` will show you the error message

   ```
   Usage: java ArithmeticCompress InputFile OutputFile
   ```

   if the length of `String[] args` is equal to zero, so you need to provide some arguments.
2. And calling `new File("E:\\output\\5.txt", args[0]);` constructor is wrong because `File(String, String)` expects the first argument to be directory and second argument to be filename. Note: you should read the Javadocs if you are not sure what method or constructor you are using!
   Here you should either use:

   ```
   File inputFile = new File("E:\\output", args[0]);
   File outputFile = new File("E:\\output", args[1]);
   ```

   and provide two arguments with only file name or you should try:

   ```
   File inputFile = new File(args[0]);
   File outputFile = new File(args[1]);
   ```

   and provide two arguments with full path of files.
3. And if you want to hard-code the file paths in the code than you should **remove** the following code:

   ```
   if (args.length == 0) {
       System.err.println("Usage: java ArithmeticCompress InputFile OutputFile");
       System.exit(1);
       return;
   }
   ```

   and hard-code the path in the File constructor as follows:

   ```
   File inputFile = new File("E:\\output\\5.txt");
   File outputFile = new File("E:\\output\\new.txt");
   ```